# The CakePHP css image path is not working

Tags: css, cakephp

I downloaded CakePHP 2.2.3 and I'm setting up my new site. However, I'm facing problems in calling the images from `view/webroot/img/logos/filename.jpg` in the CSS file. In the CSS file, I'm using this path: `background: url("../img/logos/filename.jpg")`, but the image doesn't show up. In earlier versions of CakePHP it works fine. How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your image is realyy in `app/webroot/img/logos/filename.jpg` where it should be in standard configuration (not in `view/webroot/img/logos/filename.jpg` as you have written)

Your implementation is correct, this should work for CakePHP 2.2.3 exacly the same way. Check perrmisions to the file, web server need to have read rights to your file:`app/webroot/img/logos/filename.jpg`